Immediate chunked data retrieval with HttpClient
I have HTTP server that returns data using chunked transfer.
I need to receive data as soon as it arrives, without waiting for the buffer to fill.
My current code is like
var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

using (var responseStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        var buffer = new char[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            var chunk = new string(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            // I want to consume chunk here.
            Console.WriteLine(chunk);
        }
    }
}

but in this case the data becomes available only after the buffer is filled
